# ggplot2 showing inacurate information after facet plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, visualization, facet

Ive been trying to plot some data with ggplot2 and it accurately displays the data before facetting, but after facetting - the plot gets all screwed which is visibly apparent in the winter and summer samples. name of the dataframe is Chla. see code and corresponding graphs:

```
ggplot(Chla,mapping = aes(x=Chla$Bin,y =Chla$`D.O. (mg/L)`, color = Season)) 
+ geom_jitter()
```

[Correct Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvlau.png)

Facet code:
    ggplot(Chla,mapping = aes(x=Chla$Bin,y =Chla$`D.O. (mg/L)`, color = Season)) 
    + geom_jitter()+facet_grid(Season~.)

[Wrong Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuqW2.png)

Comment: Please post your data so we can reproduce your error - [see here for how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)
You shouldn't be referencing your data within `aes`: `aes(x=Bin, y = `D.O. (mg/L)`, color = Season)`

Comment: thanks, that solved the issue

Comment: Do you want me to add it as an answer?

Comment: Sure why not, it serves as one more reference for anyone who faces the same issue, although silly on my part.

Comment: Ah looks like it's been flagged as a dupe.